# Prove that $|AB-DE|=|EF-BC|=|CD-FA|$.

Tags: geometry

The convex hexagon $ABCDEF$ has all angles equal. Prove that $|AB-DE|=|BC-EF|=|CD-FA|$.

This is from a Russian Olympiad, but the official solution is a bit unclear. It says that by extending $AB$,$CD$,and $EF$, we get an equilateral triangle with sides $AF+AB+BC$, $BC+CD+DE$,and $ED+EF+FA$. However, I'm not sure how tho proves the problem statement.

Could anyone explain this proof, or perhaps provide an alternative one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $$AF+AB+\color{red}{BC}=\color{red}{BC}+CD+DE$$ implies
$$AF+AB=CD+DE.$$
So $AF-CD=AB-DE$, and hence
$$|CD-FA|=|AB-DE|.$$

Comment: If you draw the picture, the big equilateral triangle is made of the hexagon in the middle and three small equilateral triangles at the corners.